# Retain checkbox value on page reload in form_with in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a form created using `form_with`. What I need is to retain the values submitted using that form after page reload. I am able to save the value of `text_field` but not the value of `check_box`. What should I change in my code so that I can achieve the same?

**html.erb**

```
<%= form_with url: search_path,
                      id: :search_by_filter,
                      method: :get, local: true do |f| %>   

  <div>
    <p><strong>Search by Name</strong></p>
    <%= f.label 'Name' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, value: params[:name] %>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    <%= label_tag  do %>
      <%= f.check_box :only_students, checked: params[:only_students] %>
      Show only students
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <br/>


  <div class="submit_button">
    <%= f.submit :Search %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**controller.rb**

```
def get_desired_people(params)
  people = Person.includes(:country, :state, :university).order(id: :desc)  
  people = people.where(is_student: params[:only_students]) if params[:only_students]
  people = people.where(name: params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
  people
end
```

Here I am able to retain the value of `params[:name]` but not the value of `params[:only_students]`. It always remains unchecked after form submission. How can I retain the checked and unchecked value?

Comment: Did you try with just
`
<%= f.check_box :only_students %>
`

Comment: Yes. I did. It still remains `unchecked` even when I check and submit the form.

Comment: Do your param[:only_students] remain in your URL after submission?

Comment: Yes. It is there. If unchecked, then in url after submission, `params[:only_students]=0`. If checked, then it is `params[:only_students]=0&params[:only_students]=1`

Comment: It works if I do this: `<%= f.check_box :only_students, checked: params[:only_students] == '1' ? true : false %>`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`f.check_box`</del> `check_box_tag` is expecting checked to by boolean value, and every param is a string (string is always evaluated to true if exists) so you should do:
`checked: params[:only_students].present?`
you don't have to worry about a value of param, as unchecked params are not send while posting.

EDIT:

above works for `check_box_tag`.
`f.check_box` is tricky, you should carefully read description: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box
The behaviour you described seems pretty correct, you can deal with it or switch to `check_box_tag` as a better option when not updating model attributes

Comment: That value is always present, whether the box is checked or unchecked. Like I mentioned in the comment above: If unchecked, then in url after submission, params[:only_students]=0. If checked, then it is params[:only_students]=0&params[:only_students]=1

Comment: ok. my mistake. there is a difference between `f.check_box` and `check_box_tag` and here under 'Gotcha' you'll find explanation of what is happening https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box I guess you can simply skip adding `checked: params[:only_students]` as it might be set proper without that

Comment: Yeah. I tried that. It is not retaining the checked values. It is always unchecked after form submission. It is working only when I do this: `<%= f.check_box :only_students, checked: params[:only_students] == '1' ? true : false %>`

Comment: ok, I see. It's not an update form thats why. than your solution is the one and only.
But, I can recomend one of two things: 1) make an bool in controller `@only_students = params[:only_students] == '1'` and use it where you need it 2) switch to `check_box_tag` as its better when not updating model attributes

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above did not work for me. Try this:

```
<%= check_box_tag :only_students, true, params[:only_students] %>
```